# Jquery: How to enlarge image on mouseover for dynamically generated images

Tags: jquery, image

How to enlarge image on mouseover for **dynamically generated images** from the database.I am using c# code to bind the images in the User Interface. I tried different Jquery plugins but most of them had compatibility issues with some browsers(IE 6). Kindly suggest me a way out.

Thanks.

Comment: What's have you got yet? If images are generated dinamically you may want to use `$('.image-selector').live('mouseover', function()...`

Answer (score 1):

If you are dynamically adding images to your page (from a database or other external source), your first issue is how to ensure jQuery is made aware of them.

JQuery has a number of event listeners for dynamically-generated content, such as $.live() and $.delegate().  You will want to assign a listener for a content region to look out for any new images being loaded by using one of those two jQuery functions.

Once your code is aware of a newly-added image, your next task is to add the enlarge / shrink behaviour.  Depending on what you want to have happen, your likely best option is to use jQuery's $.hover() event.  So your code will look something like this:

```
$("#myContentRegion").delegate("img", "hover", function(){
    $(this).animate({ 
            width: 200, height: 200 
        }, 5000, function() {
    $(this).animate({ width: 100, height: 100 });
  });

});
```